# How do I change Imageresource quickly?

Tags: android

I want to make it so that once I press a button, it moves and does an animation by quickly swapping the src of the imageview mid animation.

I've tried to use Thread.sleep .

```
first.setImageResource(R.drawable.cata2);
                first.setImageResource(R.drawable.catb2);
```

ObjectAnimation Code

```
x += 10
first.setImageResource(R.drawable.cata2);
                ObjectAnimator d = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(first, "translationX", x);
                d.setDuration(50);
                d.start();
```

It always just switches to cata2.

Comment: Can you show some of related codes ? What animationa re you using ? fading, rorating etc. if that the case we can use `animationListener`

Answer (score 1):

> Try this one. If the changing image resource not working, try to change it in background resource. Just adjust some duration and the thread sleep.

in C#:

**Try to put this all inside the listener of your button**

**Setting up the Animation**

`var clockwise = AnimationUtils.LoadAnimation(this.Activity, Resource.Animation.clockwise);`
`clockwise.Duration = 2000;`

**To set your first to cata2**

```
this.Activity.RunOnUiThread(() =>
{
first.setImageResource(R.drawable.cata2);
});
```

**To change with animation from cata2 to catb2**

```
Thread t = new Thread(delegate ()

{

first.StartAnimation(clockwise);

Thread.Sleep(500);

this.Activity.RunOnUiThread(() =>

{

first.setImageResource(R.drawable.catb2);

first.ClearAnimation();

return;

});

});

t.Start();
```

Comment: Well, I use Java. =(

Comment: oh it's okay bro. they're not too different to each other :) just try it. I'm use java before and now, migrate in c#. that's why I can tell that to you. ** but I'm newbie too and sorry for my poor english**

Answer (score 0):

We can add a listeter to your animation

d.addListener(this);

Then generate overridess

```
@Override
public void onAnimationStart(Animator animation){
//add some codes
}

@Override
public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation){
//add some codes
}

@Override
public void onAnimationRepeat(Animator animation){
 //add some codes
}

@Override
public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animation){

}
```